# Does the Dirac operator have spectrum bound from below?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, dirac-equation, antimatter

- [**Does the Dirac operator have spectrum bound from below?**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spectrum)

Dirac operator is a differential operator that is a formal square root, or half-iterate, of a second-order operator such as a Laplacian.

It seems that the Dirac operator
$$D=\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\ \equiv \not \partial$$
can have an energy spectrum for the particle excitations:
$$
E =\sqrt{p^2+m^2} \geq 0
$$
if we consider the operator $(i D -m)$.

There could also be anti-particle (positron) excitations which have positive energy:
$$
 E =  \sqrt{p^2+m^2} \geq 0.
$$

But if we use the Dirac sea picture where we create the anti-particle excitation by creating a hole in the Dirac sea. Then there is **a sea of negative energy unbounded from below**.

$$
\sum_p E(p) =  -\sqrt{p^2+m^2} \to -\infty \ll 0.
$$

The anti-particle (positron) excitation has energy from comparing the filled and the empty Dirac sea at the energy $-\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$:
$$
0-(-\sqrt{p^2+m^2} )=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}.
$$

So question: [**Does the Dirac operator have spectrum bound from below?**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spectrum)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the case of a 1d spacetime:    $D = i\partial_t$.  This operator does not have a spectrum which is bounded from below.

Note however that the Dirac operator $D$ is not the energy operator of the quantum field theory of Dirac fermions.  It doesn't really matter if the Dirac operator is bounded below.

Comment: Why would you say that that the time derivative operator has no lower bound for the spectrum?

Comment: @DanielC Because $i\partial_t e^{-i\omega t}=\omega e^{-i\omega t}$, where $\omega$ can be any real number, so the spectrum of $i\partial_t$ is the whole real line.